# my submit form on select change script doesn't runs on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, forms, jquery-mobile

The following script doesn't runs in Chrome, but runs fine on all other browser.
any tips?

```
<div data-role="page"  > 
<!--  start header -->
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#nav-panelmenusx" data-icon="bars" data-position="left" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext">Menu</a>
<a href="#nav-panelinfodx" data-icon="info" data-position="right" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext">Info</a>
<h1 style="margin:0;padding:0">
<form action="" name="selectloc" id="selectloc" method="post" data-ajax="false">
 <input type="hidden" name="setssid" value="1">
  <select name="SSID" data-mini="true" id = "selectlocation" data-native-menu="false" data-force-dialog="true" >
  <option value="optionval_1" >option1</option>
  <option value="option_n">optionN</option>
  </select>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#selectlocation').change(function() {
$('#selectloc').submit();
});
});
 </script>
 </h1>
 </div>
 <!-- /header -->
 .......
```

Environment:
LAMP
Jquerymobile 1.4.5 
jquery 1.9.1
PHP 5.4
FB API 2.2

Runs like a charme in all browser but not chrome, where the form is not submitted on select.
thx

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: When in Chrome,  open your debugger (F12)...are there any errors in the console tab when/after you reload the page?

Comment: Chrome debugger doesn't find any error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove white space character around the id of the option element.

```
id = "selectlocation"
id="selectlocation"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not a big fan of jQuery.... but why not just use the old good:
 **onchange="this.form.submit();"**

```
<select name="SSID" data-mini="true" id = "selectlocation" data-native-menu="false" data-force-dialog="true" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="optionval_1" >option1</option>
    <option value="option_n">optionN</option>
</select>
```

Unless you have other big scripting in the form.....

Comment: Done, no result on chrome and more problems on firefox because it duplicates the url attribute at every selection:  .... #&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog

Comment: strange... it works perfectly for me. What version of chrome do you have.... and if you use this way you should disable the jQuery way... did you do that ?

Comment: I belive the error lies somwere else in the code..... look in the (f12) debugger.....